# Marshmallow, starting SMS app via Intent and pressing back end up on home screen instead of in calling application

Tags: android, sms, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm calling SMS app with following code:

```
public static void startSmsIntent(Activity context, String value) {
    Intent smsIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("smsto:"+value) );
    try{
        context.startActivity(smsIntent);
    }
    catch( ActivityNotFoundException e ){

    }
}
```

It opens conversation thread in default SMS app. After pressing back button insteaad of returning to calling application, Default SMS app conversation list is displayed. Pressing back again, and I'm ending on home screen and only way to get back to my app is via Recent apps chooser. Below Marshmallow it works as expected, first back brings me to calling application screen. I tried to use extra flag:

```
smsIntent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
```

which was mentioned in different context in the documentaiton - [here](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html), but no luck.

Comment: If you want to finish the SMS app after the send, you can try `putBoolean("exit_on_sent", true)`. Although I'd imagine you'll get the same behavior as you describe if the user backs out without sending, so you might `startActivityForResult()` instead.

Comment: @MikeM. neither of those method makes any difference. Extra boolean does nothing, when starting activity for result, onActivityResult() is called before Sms app launches, so I guess it is declared as singleTask.